# Why does the letter "c" appear in text fields in a plugin options page?

Tags: php, html, text

I'm try to develop a small WordPress plugin with some text fields.

At the first activation of the plugin, the text field values should be empty but the letter "c" appear in text fields.

See [this screenshot](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0e03a0kb59).

Here's is my code used in my plugin options page:

```
<p>
<?php $js_footer_exceptions1 = ( isset( $sbp_options['sbp_js_footer_exceptions1'] ) ) ? $sbp_options['sbp_js_footer_exceptions1'] : ''; ?>
<input type="text" name="sbp_settings[sbp_js_footer_exceptions1]" id="sbp_settings[sbp_js_footer_exceptions1]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $js_footer_exceptions1 ); ?>" />
</p>
```

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: I guess `$js_footer_exceptions1` is set to `c`.

Comment: What does `esc_attr` do? Thats probably where you have to look.

Comment: @Barmar Nothing is set at the first plugin activation.

Comment: Then it must be what `esc_attr` does with an empty string.

Comment: @putvande even I use without it, the "c" is still there. `<?php echo $js_footer_exceptions1; ?>`

Comment: Than as @Barmar said, it must be your variable is set to `c`. An `input` field does not put the `c` there by itself.

Comment: What do you see if you put the echo statement before the input field?

Comment: Please show `var_dump($sbp_options)`

Comment: @Barmar `string(7) "checked" `

Comment: There's your problem. It's not an associative array, so asking for `$sbp_options['sbp_js_footer_exceptions1']` makes no sense. It's treating it as a string element accessor, and the argument is converted to `0`, so you get the first character of the string.

Comment: You probably should be looking for `sbp_js_footer_exceptions1` in some other variable that contains an array of options.

Comment: No luck. The "c" is still there.